# Get value from xml in azure pipelines

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have azure pipeline .yml file

Here is it

```
    steps:
  - task: CmdLine@1
    displayName: "Run Unit Tests"
    inputs:
      filename: 'OpenCover.4.7.1221\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe'
      arguments: '
        -target:"dotnet.exe"
        -targetargs:"test $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\Home.BLL.Tests.Unit\bin\net6.0\Home.BLL.Tests.Unit.dll $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\Home.Core.Tests.Unit\bin\net6.0\Home.Core.Tests.Unit.dll $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\Home.Domain.Tests.Unit\bin\net6.0\Home.Domain.Tests.Unit.dll --no-build --configuration debug -l:trx;LogFileName=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\test-results.xml"
        -filter:"+[Home.BLL]* +[Home.Core]* +[Home.Domain]* -[*Tests.Unit]*"
        -output:"$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\opencover-coverage.xml"
        -register:user
        -hideskipped:All
        -skipautoprops
        -returntargetcode
        -excludebyfile:*\*Generated.cs'
      workingFolder: 'src\packages'
      failOnStandardError: true

  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: 'Get-Content -Path $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\opencover-coverage.xml'

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\test-results.xml'
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: NUnit
      testResultsFiles: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\test-results.xml'

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish XUnit Test Results $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\test-results.xml'
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: VSTest
      testResultsFiles: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\test-results.xml'
      testRunTitle: "Unit tests XUnit"

  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage from $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\cobertura-coverage.xml'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
      summaryFileLocation: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\cobertura-coverage.xml'
```

in this step   `PowerShell@2`

I get file content

Here is content example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoverageSession xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="4.7.1221.0">
  <Summary numSequencePoints="2826" visitedSequencePoints="163" numBranchPoints="2210" visitedBranchPoints="136" sequenceCoverage="5.77" branchCoverage="6.15" maxCyclomaticComplexity="22" minCyclomaticComplexity="1" maxCrapScore="506" minCrapScore="1" visitedClasses="19" numClasses="306" visitedMethods="100" numMethods="1490" />
  <Modules>
```

I need to get `sequenceCoverage="5.77"` and `branchCoverage="6.15"` values and show error and stop pipeline if  one of them less then 9

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has pretty advanced XML parsing built-in, you can convert a string to an XML object and navigate its properties:

```
$xml = [xml] '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoverageSession xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="4.7.1221.0">
  <Summary numSequencePoints="2826" visitedSequencePoints="163" numBranchPoints="2210" visitedBranchPoints="136" sequenceCoverage="5.77" branchCoverage="6.15" maxCyclomaticComplexity="22" minCyclomaticComplexity="1" maxCrapScore="506" minCrapScore="1" visitedClasses="19" numClasses="306" visitedMethods="100" numMethods="1490" />
</CoverageSession>'

# $xml = [xml] (get-content -raw $pathToXml)

[double]$branchcoverage = $xml.CoverageSession.Summary.branchCoverage
[double]$sequenceCoverage = $xml.CoverageSession.Summary.sequenceCoverage

if ($sequenceCoverage -lt 9.0) {
  write-output "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Sequence Coverage dipped below 9."
  Write-Output "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Sequence Coverage dipped below 9."
}

if ($branchcoverage -lt 9.0) {
  write-output "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Branch Coverage dipped below 9."
  Write-Output "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Branch Coverage dipped below 9."
}
```

The code above [issues a special logging statement to communicate the status back to Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#complete-finish-timeline).

The result of the above code will look like this:

[image]

Instead of using `- task: PowerShell@2`, you could ure the shorthand syntax to make everything a bit more readable:

```
- pwsh: |
      $xml = [xml] '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <CoverageSession xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="4.7.1221.0">
        <Summary numSequencePoints="2826" visitedSequencePoints="163" numBranchPoints="2210" visitedBranchPoints="136" sequenceCoverage="5.77" branchCoverage="6.15" maxCyclomaticComplexity="22" minCyclomaticComplexity="1" maxCrapScore="506" minCrapScore="1" visitedClasses="19" numClasses="306" visitedMethods="100" numMethods="1490" />
      </CoverageSession>'

      # $xml = [xml] (get-content -raw $pathToXml)

      [double]$branchcoverage = $xml.CoverageSession.Summary.branchCoverage
      [double]$sequenceCoverage = $xml.CoverageSession.Summary.sequenceCoverage

      if ($sequenceCoverage -lt 9.0) {
        write-output "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Sequence Coverage dipped below 9."
        Write-Output "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Sequence Coverage dipped below 9."
      }

      if ($branchcoverage -lt 9.0) {
        write-output "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Branch Coverage dipped below 9."
        Write-Output "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Branch Coverage dipped below 9."
      }
```

Comment: You may need to add some extra error handling and checking whether properties and files exist and all ;).

Comment: I got exit -1 and no errors, so output not showing `Branch Coverage dipped below 9` text @jessehouwing

Comment: For some reason the Failure reason isn't printed anymore... It used to do that. I've added a line to log the error, that *is* shown.

Comment: But as I understand this will not fail step , just log?

Comment: It will fail the step. the logissue writes the error to the log, the result=failed will fail the workflow. If you want to exit early, you'll need to add the exit statement back in.

Comment: strange stuff, I wrote code like this

`- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Check code coverage"
    inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: '$xml = $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\opencover-coverage.xml
        [double]$sequenceCoverage = $xml.CoverageSession.Summary.sequenceCoverage

        if ($sequenceCoverage -lt 5.6) {
        Write-Output "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Sequence Coverage dipped below 5.6"
        }'

and task failed.

Coverage is 5.77

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253556/discussion-between-eugene-sukh-and-jessehouwing).